# Sorting DataTables after changing values with JS

Tags: javascript, datatables

I've been using DataTables 1.9.4 and everything looks really nice and is formatted well, but I am having some trouble with sorting columns.  I populate the table with data when the page loads, and then later on I change some of the values using JS.  After the data has changed the sorting function no longer seems to work correctly.  I ran a few tests and realized that the initial data that is input is saved and it is always sorted by that and not the current value.    I was wondering if there is any way to have it save the new values and sort by those.

Thanks
-Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the datatables doesn't support this kind of operation. But I found this I think it's helpful. though it seems a little complicated. please refer to this url:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to keep messing around with this plug-in and try to get it working correctly

Comment: try to enjoy it, for some point it's very convenient, but sometimes it's not very good for some logics.